# Make data tip appear when mouse hovers the chart, not only when hovers data points

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to find a non-ugly solution for this, but still with no luck.
I want a data tip to appear when mouse pointer is over any point of the chart, not only when pointer is directly over a data point.

Comment: Show some code; explain what you've tried to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer your looking for, but we found the Axiis Visualization Framework far easier to customize and add/modify any and all of the functionality as we saw fit.
http://www.axiis.org/

Comment: yeah, there are few nice charting frameworks and kits for flex, but the problem is we are asked to use only built-in components :(

Comment: Well, the solution is ugly, but a timer on the chart, on mousemove reset it, when the timer limit is reached call a function to display a popupanchor/tooltip, at that point you would need to grab the mouse x and y positions and interpolate the cursor position vs the datapoints.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying this future on my project. Still working on. Below code gives you solution for your problem.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:SeriesInterpolate id="interp" elementOffset="10"
                          duration="200" minimumElementDuration="10" />

    <mx:SolidColorStroke id="st" color="#92D050" weight="8" />  
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.charts.ChartItem;
        import mx.charts.chartClasses.Series;

        import mx.charts.series.items.LineSeriesItem;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;         

        private var dummyGeneratorTimer:Timer;
        private var dummyUpdateTimer:Timer;

        private static const DATA_INTERVAL:int = 600;//8;

        private static const ARRAY_SIZE:int = 500;

        private var chartIndex:int = 0;

        [Bindable]
        private var chartData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
            { Time: 1, parameter1: 2200, parameter2: 1700, parameter3: 1500, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1100, parameter6:900 },
            { Time: 2, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1450, parameter4: 1200, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:800  },
            { Time: 3, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1700, parameter3: 1500, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1100, parameter6:900  },
            { Time: 4, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1450, parameter4: 1200, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:800  },
            { Time: 5, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1750, parameter3: 1500, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1100, parameter6:900  },
            { Time: 5, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1400, parameter4: 1200, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:800 },
            { Time: 7, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1700, parameter3: 1500, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:900 },
            { Time: 8, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1600, parameter4: 1200, parameter5: 1100, parameter6:800 },
            { Time: 9, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1800, parameter3: 1400, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:900 },
            { Time: 10, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1500, parameter4: 1200, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:800 },
            { Time: 11, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1700, parameter3: 1400, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1100, parameter6:900 },
            { Time: 12, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1400, parameter4: 1200, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:800 },
            { Time: 13, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1500, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1100, parameter6:900 },
            { Time: 14, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1700, parameter3: 1400, parameter4: 1200, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:800 },
            { Time: 15, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1500, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1100, parameter6:900 },
            { Time: 16, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1700, parameter3: 1400, parameter4: 1200, parameter5: 1000, parameter6:800 },
            { Time: 17, parameter1: 1900, parameter2: 1600, parameter3: 1500, parameter4: 1300, parameter5: 1100, parameter6:900 }]);

        protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            dummyGeneratorTimer = new Timer(DATA_INTERVAL); // 8 millisecond

        }
        private var count:Number = 17;

        private function populateData(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            var obj:Object = new Object();
            obj.Time= (++count).toString();
            obj.parameter1=  randomRange(1900,1900);
            obj.parameter2= randomRange(1600,1700);
            obj.parameter3=  randomRange(1400,1500);
            obj.parameter4=  randomRange(1200,1300);
            obj.parameter5=  randomRange(1000,1100);
            obj.parameter6=  randomRange(800,900);

            chartData.refresh();

            chartData.addItem(obj);
            linechart.width += 10;
        }


        private function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
        {    
            return (Math.round(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
        }


        protected function scope_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(scopeBtn.label  == 'Scope1'){
                scopeBtn.label = 'Stop Scope';
                dummyGeneratorTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, populateData,false,0,true);
                dummyGeneratorTimer.start();
            }
            else{
                scopeBtn.label = 'Scope1';
                dummyGeneratorTimer.stop(); 
                dummyGeneratorTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, populateData,false); 
            }

        }


        private var activeSeries:LineSeries;

        private var activePoint:LineSeriesItem;

    /*  protected function linechart_itemMouseMoveHandler(event:ChartItemEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(event.hitData && event.hitData.element is LineSeries){
                activeSeries = event.hitData.element as LineSeries;
                activePoint = (event.hitData.chartItem as LineSeriesItem);

                var tmpArr:Array = activeSeries.dataTransform.invertTransform(linechart.mouseX, linechart.mouseY);
                for(var i:int=0;i<tmpArr.length;i++){
                    trace("i:"+tmpArr[i]);
                }
            }
        }*/

        private function dataTipHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var leftPoint:Point = new Point(linechart.mouseX,0);

            //leftPoint = event.target.localToGlobal(leftPoint);

            //leftPoint = linechart.localToContent(leftPoint);
            //var rightPoint:Point = new Point(chart.mouseX,0);
            var leftArr:Array = lineSeries.localToData(leftPoint);

            var series:Series;
            var item:ChartItem;

            for each(var s:Series in linechart.series){
                // initialize/empty dataTipItems of all series.
                s.dataTipItems = [];
                series = s;
                item = series.items[leftArr[0]-3];
                if(item != null)
                    series.dataTipItems.push(item);
            }

            linechart.showAllDataTips = true;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button id="scopeBtn" label="Scope1" click="scope_clickHandler(event)"/>
<!--<s:Button id="update" label="update" click="update_clickHandler()"/>-->
```

</s:layout>-->

```
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout horizontalAlign="right" 
                            paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" 
                            paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10"/>
    </s:layout>
<!--<s:HSlider change="drawData()" liveDragging="true" value="50" id="quadBoundary" minimum="-200" maximum="200" width="100%" />      -->
    <mx:LineChart id="linechart" color="0xffffff" height="100%" width="100%" cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on"
                  showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{chartData}" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="20" seriesFilters="[]"
                  gutterLeft="40" gutterTop="0" paddingTop="0"
                  dataTipRenderer="MyDataTip" mouseMove="dataTipHandler(event)">
        <!-- mouseSensitivity="20"  dataTipMode="multiple" showAllDataTips="false"  itemMouseDown="linechart_itemMouseMoveHandler(event)" -->

        <mx:backgroundElements>
            <mx:GridLines id="gridLines" gridDirection="vertical" cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on"                   
                          verticalTickAligned="true"> <!--verticalChangeCount="1"-->
                <mx:verticalStroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xffffff"
                               weight="0"
                               alpha="0.5" />
                </mx:verticalStroke>
            <!--    <mx:horizontalStroke>
                     Set alpha to 0 so stroke isn't visible. 
                    <mx:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000"
                               weight="0"
                               alpha="0.0" />
                </mx:horizontalStroke>
                <mx:horizontalFill>
                    <mx:SolidColor color="0x000000"
                                   alpha="0.1" />
                </mx:horizontalFill>-->
            </mx:GridLines> 
        <!--<dataShapes:DataDrawingCanvas id="canvas" includeInRanges="true"/>
```

-->
             -->

```
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <!--<mx:LinearAxis id="h1" autoAdjust="true"/>-->
            <mx:CategoryAxis id="h1" categoryField="Time"/>
            <!--<mx:DateTimeAxis id="h1" autoAdjust="true" displayLocalTime="true" interval="11"  />-->

        </mx:horizontalAxis>

        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis id="v1" baseAtZero="false" autoAdjust="false" alignLabelsToInterval="false"/>
        </mx:verticalAxis>


        <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>              
            <mx:AxisRenderer placement="right" axis="{v1}" showLine="true" showLabels="true" visible="true"/>           
        </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>

        <!-- horizontal axis renderer -->
        <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{h1}" minorTickPlacement="none" minorTickLength="3"
                             canDropLabels="false">
                <mx:minorTickStroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#BBCCDD" weight="2"/>
                </mx:minorTickStroke>
            </mx:AxisRenderer>
<!--            
        <charts:ScrollableAxisRenderer axis="{h1}" id="scrollAxis" tickPlacement="none"   placement="bottom"
                                       labelGap="3"  scrollBarThemeColor="blue" />
        -->
        </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>


        <mx:series> 
        <!--    <mx:LineSeries yField="parameter1" showDataEffect="{interp}" form="step" sortOnXField="false" displayName="Parameter1" 
                           verticalAxis="{v1}" horizontalAxis="{h1}"  cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on"
                           itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.CircleItemRenderer" radius="5">
                <mx:lineStroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#C05046" weight="3" alpha="0.9" />
                </mx:lineStroke>
            </mx:LineSeries>-->

            <components:MyLineSeries id="lineSeries" xField="Time" yField="parameter1" displayName="parameter1" form="segment" showDataEffect="{interp}" 
                                     verticalAxis="{v1}" horizontalAxis="{h1}" cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on" 
                                     lineStroke="{st}" itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.ShadowBoxItemRenderer">
                <components:lineSegmentRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <dashedLine:DashedLineRenderer pattern="[20,20,5,20]"/>
                    </fx:Component>
                </components:lineSegmentRenderer>

            </components:MyLineSeries>

            <mx:LineSeries xField="Time" yField="parameter2" showDataEffect="{interp}" form="curve" displayName="Parameter2"  verticalAxis="{v1}" horizontalAxis="{h1}"  
                           cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on" itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.CircleItemRenderer">
                <mx:lineStroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#036CBA" weight="3" alpha="0.9" />
                </mx:lineStroke>
            </mx:LineSeries>
            <mx:LineSeries xField="Time" yField="parameter3" showDataEffect="{interp}" form="step" displayName="Parameter3"  verticalAxis="{v1}" horizontalAxis="{h1}" 
                           cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on" itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.CrossItemRenderer">
                <mx:lineStroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#9DBB61" weight="3" alpha="0.9" />
                </mx:lineStroke>
            </mx:LineSeries>
            <mx:LineSeries xField="Time" yField="parameter4" showDataEffect="{interp}" form="curve" displayName="Parameter4"  verticalAxis="{v1}"  horizontalAxis="{h1}"
                           cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on" itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.DiamondItemRenderer" radius="5">
                <mx:lineStroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#4BACC6" weight="3" alpha="0.9" />
                </mx:lineStroke>
            </mx:LineSeries>
            <mx:LineSeries xField="Time" yField="parameter5" showDataEffect="{interp}" form="curve" displayName="Parameter5"  verticalAxis="{v1}" horizontalAxis="{h1}"
                           cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on" itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.TriangleItemRenderer">
                <mx:lineStroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#ED9853" weight="3" alpha="0.9" />
                </mx:lineStroke>
            </mx:LineSeries>
            <mx:LineSeries xField="Time" yField="parameter6" showDataEffect="{interp}" form="curve" displayName="Parameter6"  verticalAxis="{v1}" horizontalAxis="{h1}"
                           cacheAsBitmap="true" cachePolicy="on" itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.BoxItemRenderer"
                           legendMarkerRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.TriangleItemRenderer">
                <mx:lineStroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#7030A0" weight="3" alpha="0.9" />
                </mx:lineStroke>
            </mx:LineSeries>


        </mx:series>

    <mx:annotationElements>
            <local:RangeSelector id="rs"/>
        </mx:annotationElements>


    </mx:LineChart>

    <mx:Legend dataProvider="{linechart}" color="0xffffff"/>

</s:SkinnableContainer>
```